# Only update changed fields (Hibernate + Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I feel like I've been looking for an answer to this forever, but can't seem to find it (or rather, find one that works).

I have multiple forms in my web-app, and most of the time I want to only update some fields, while leaving others as is; even though they may be blank.

But Hibernate overwrites my fields if I don't explicitly include them in my form, but I feel like including hidden fields with unused attributes all over the place is a very bad option.

Also, even though I include a password field - it just returns empty instead of somehow including the encrypted password.

I have tried with `@DynamicUpdate` on my entities, but this doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share a meaningful piece of your code with us: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It sounds like you need to decouple your web layer from your persistence layer. Load the entity after the form is submitted, copy the fields you want from your web model to the entity and save it.